# Why does max_leaves conflicts with monotone_contraints in Python xgboost?

Tags: python, constraints, xgboost, monotone

I have trained the following XGboost:

```
model = XGBClassifier(
    objective='binary:logistic',
    base_score=0.5, 
    booster='gbtree', 
    colsample_bylevel=1,
    colsample_bynode=1, 
    colsample_bytree=1,
    enable_categorical=False, 
    gamma=2, 
    gpu_id=-1,
    importance_type=None, 
    interaction_constraints=[],
    learning_rate=0.09999999999999995, 
    max_delta_step=0,
    #max_leaves = 2,
    min_child_weight=0.9999999999999993, 
    monotone_constraints='(1,1,-1,-1,-1)',
    n_estimators=40, 
    n_jobs=1, 
    nthread=1, 
    num_parallel_tree=1,
    predictor='auto',
    random_state=0, 
    reg_alpha=0.0009765625, 
    reg_lambda=1,
    scale_pos_weight=1, 
    silent=True, 
    subsample=1,
    tree_method='exact',
    validate_parameters=1, 
    pred_contribs=True,  
    verbosity=None)
```

As you can see, I have commented out `max_leaves = 2` (which means that, by default, `max_leaves = 0`). The model is trained with no issues.

Then, I have tried to train the same `XGBoost`  BUT I have specified the `max_leaves = 2`:

```
model = XGBClassifier(
    objective='binary:logistic',
    base_score=0.5, 
    booster='gbtree', 
    colsample_bylevel=1,
    colsample_bynode=1, 
    colsample_bytree=1,
    enable_categorical=False, 
    gamma=2, 
    gpu_id=-1,
    importance_type=None, 
    interaction_constraints=[],
    learning_rate=0.09999999999999995, 
    max_delta_step=0,
    max_leaves = 2,
    min_child_weight=0.9999999999999993, 
    monotone_constraints='(1,1,-1,-1,-1)',
    n_estimators=40, 
    n_jobs=1, 
    nthread=1, 
    num_parallel_tree=1,
    predictor='auto',
    random_state=0, 
    reg_alpha=0.0009765625, 
    reg_lambda=1,
    scale_pos_weight=1, 
    silent=True, 
    subsample=1,
    tree_method='exact',
    validate_parameters=1, 
    pred_contribs=True,  
    verbosity=None)
```

And the model does not train. In Spyder console I see this error:

```
Restarting kernel...
```

If I try the same in Visual Studio I get an error such as `Aborted!`.

If I set the `max_leaves` to be between 1 and 11 (when the `monotone_contraints` are specified), then the model does not get trained. If the number of leaves is greater than 11, then the model trains fine.

**Question 1. Why is that?**

Then, I have removed the `monotone_constraints` and set the number of `max_leaves` between 1 and 11 and the model gets trained.

**Question 2. Why would the `monotone_constraints` interfere with the `max_leaves`? I have tried this on different datasets (with low and large number of records and features), and that's what I have consistently noticed: if the `monotone_contraints` is set, then the `max_leaves` must be either 0 or greater than 11. I don't understand why. Has anyone come across this issue before?**